# jquery event: isDefaultPrevented(), isPropagationStopped(), isImmediatePropagationStopped usage

Tags: jquery

Is it really worthful having the functions isDefaultPrevented(), isPropagationStopped() and isImmediatePropagationStopped()? Any situation where you used these functions?

Answer (score 3):

They're useful if you have your own service layer that your event handlers all use. A good example might be an audit/logging layer.

Comment: can u plz describe more, possibly with an eg?

Comment: Well, @Arun, I personally haven't felt the need to use them :-)  However I feel that just in terms of basic API design, those functions almost *have* to be there.

Comment: I recently used them in a case where I had a global event listener for  in-page anchor links that I wanted to smooth scroll on click. If the event isDefaultPrevented or isPropagationStopped then I don't do anything, assuming another click listener already took control. Otherwise, I do the JS scrolly dance.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this very old question, but it is still very relevant.

I have a number of plugins that broadcast custom events, using `trigger`, and I need to know if any receiver cancels my `navigate` event:

e.g. `isDefaultPrevented`

```
// Inside a click event
var evt = $.Event('navigate');
var nav = {url: "testurl"};

// Let the item and ancestors know I wish to navigate
$(this).trigger(evt, nav);

// If nothing else says stop the event
if (!evt.isDefaultPrevented()){
    // handler the navigation here
    window.location = nav.url;
}
```

`isPropagationStopped` and `isImmediatePropagationStopped` is only useful if you need to know if the event did not bubble up. I can't say I have found a case that needed these `yet`.